# Check for pandas duplicates in a PEP8 way

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, pep8

The simplest way I can think of to check to duplicates in a pandas dataframe is the following:

```
if (df["col1"].value_counts() > 1).sum() > 0:
    raise ValueError("dupes in column 'col1'!")
```

The problem is that this is not PEP8 compliant.  The code-checker in my IDE (I use PyCharm) tells me:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'sum' for class 'bool'

What is an acceptable way to check for pandas duplicates, without adding multiple lines of code?

Comment: For the benefit of the community, can you explain *why* your code is not PEP8 compliant?

Comment: I (maybe incorrectly) don't see how this isn't PEP8 compliant.

Comment: @jpp I've edited my question to explain the warning I get.

Comment: That isn't PEP8 though.. that's your linter having trouble.

Comment: You should file a bug on the linter. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with PEP8. In fact, your error seems to be a false positive: your IDE appears to be *guessing* that the result of a comparison operation is Boolean and therefore has no `sum` or `any` method.

But there is nothing wrong with your syntax: `df["col1"].value_counts() > 1` returns a Boolean `pd.Series` object, which does have `sum` and `any` methods.

The only solution I can suggest is use another IDE. Or disable your code checker.

Comment: Thanks @jpp.  While this is technically correct, switching IDE's over a minor linting issue feels overkill.

Comment: @lebelinoz, Sure.. so disabling the code checking feature may be the way forward. I am, of course, biased. I'd rather use Notepad than PyCharm.

Comment: @lebelinoz. No need to switch IDE's or disable the whole code checking feature. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/suppressing-inspections.html

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with PEP8-compliance, but what you are probably looking for is:

```
if (df.col1.value_counts() > 1).any():
    raise ValueError("dupes in column 'col1'!")
```

Note that this ignores `None`/`NaN`/`NaT` values, i.e. you would not find duplicate `na`'s using this method. If you need that, add `dropna=False` to the `value_counts` call.

Note that this is not the fastest approach, however. A faster test would be, for example:

```
if len(set(df.col1.values)) != len(df.col1):
    ...
```

Comment: This gives me the same sort of warning:  `Unresolved attribute reference 'any' for class 'bool'`

Comment: Ah, you are talking about the IDE warnings, I see. Then @jpp explained the situation correctly in a neighboring answer. Depending on the IDE or a checker there might be a way to disable the warning for this particular line.

Comment: Switching IDE's feels like overkill, but I like your `len(set(...)) != len(...)` solution if it makes my program more efficient (I needed to add some `.dropna()` modifiers to it).